# Error when testing with jasmine John Papa controller as vm

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test a controller as vm, but get error

Main module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ds', [
            'ionic',
            'ui.router',
            'ds.controllers',
            'ds.services',
            'ds.filters',
            'underscore',
            'ionicLazyLoad',
            'ngCordova',
            'ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch'
        ])
})();
```

The controller code is as below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ds')
        .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

    LoginCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope"];

    function LoginCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.model = { name: "controllerAs vm test" };

    }
})();
```

my jasmine test:

```
   'use strict';

    describe('LoginCtrl', function() {
        var LoginCtrl;
        beforeEach(module('ds'));

        beforeEach(function() {
            inject(function($injector) {
                LoginCtrl = $injector.get('$controller')('LoginCtrl', {});
            });
        });

    it('LoginCtrl should be defined and LoginCtrl.name is equal to controllerAs vm test', function() {
        expect(LoginCtrl).toBeDefined();
        expect(LoginCtrl.name).toEqual("controllerAs vm test");
    });
});
```

And get this error:

```
15 11 2016 14:40:33.608:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/modules/login/login.controller.js".
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LoginCtrl LoginCtrl should be defined and LoginCtrl.name is equal to controllerAs vm test FAILED
    /Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13218:53
    forEach@/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:24
    loadModules@/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:12
    createInjector@/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13104:22
    workFn@/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
    inject@/Users/roman.ishchiv/Documents/dogshows/www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3054:46
    unit-tests/login.controller.test.js:8:15
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    unit-tests/login.controller.test.js:14:38
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginCtrl.name') in unit-tests/login.controller.test.js (line 15)
    unit-tests/login.controller.test.js:15:25
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.001 secs / 0.017 secs)
```

And this part of my karma config file:

```
files: [
    '../lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
    '../lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    '../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    '../js/*.js',
    '../js/**/*.js',
    '../modules/**/*.js',
    'unit-tests/*.js',
],
```

Has someone any suggestion on how to solve this problem or has a guide on how to work with John Papa angular style guide and unit testing?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem was with karma config file. If u  are using jquery, u must include her before ionic or angular file
Like this: 

files: [
 '../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    '../lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
    '../lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
   .....
],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this kind of construct for testing (although we use ES6 vs ES5):

```
let vm;
inject((_$controller_, _$rootScope_) => {
  vm = _$controller_(SomeControllerImport,
    { $scope: _$rootscope.$new() });
});
```

Then in your tests you can refer directly to vm like you would inside your normal controller code:

```
expect(vm.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

And so on.